# Create a horizontal ListView in Android Studio

Tags: listview, android-studio

I would like to know how to create a ListView in Android Studio or any way to visualize information so that it is intuitive and pleasing to the eye but horizontal. besides having some event by touching an item. I can not use a vertical ListView because it takes too much space and would not have space to other elements . And I do not like having so many layouts created .
I accept any proposal.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days you want to be using RecyclerView instead of list view. It uses a layout manager as well as an adapter. The linear layout manager can be set to horizontal.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Okay, I should have explained myself badly, I 'm using 5 Right Now Buttons ( playing with your display to show, a text and that when the press do things ) . And what I want is to do as the movement of normal ListView , only horizontal and not have a fixed number of elements

Comment: I think you might want to read a bit more about RecyclerView, it behaves very like a list view only it is faster and more feature rich. It is part of the support library. Is uses an adapter just like a list view (so only one xml layout required) but forces the view holder pattern. You then set a layout manager to tell the RecyclerView how to display the views from the adapter. It means with one adapter you can lay the views out vertical, horizontal in a grid really how ever you want. (horizontal in this case)

Comment: If someone has the same problem , I found the solution on this website :